# Ubuntu timezone changed but mongodb still prints datetime based on previous timezone

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, timezone

I used following commands to change `timezone` in my Ubuntu 16.04 server

`sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Seoul /etc/localtime` and `tzselect`

After typing `date` I get the correct datetime.

But on mongodb when I print time of recently added document by `res.ops[0]._id.getTimestamp()` I still get the datetime prior to the timezone change.

I restarted mongodb and the server itself. But still no change. And I am using node.js as backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the time as UTC and then on the server side get the document with time and apply to it your wanted timezone. That way you decouple timezones from your data.